# plotOptions.column.pointPlacement consistency issue

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I am using Highcharts v6.0.7.

**Objective**:
I need to center align column bars “on” x-axis tickmarks.

**Configuration**:
Highcharts column chart
X-axis is datetime and non-categorized.
I am using pointPlacement with a numeric value in order to center align the column bars of my chart over x-axis tickmarks.

**Issue**:
Yesterday, a certain numeric value for pointPlacement centered the column bars “on” tickmarks. However, today, all configuration remaining same, the column bars are at an offset from the x-axis tickmarks.

**Questions**:

1. Is this a bug with Highcharts or should I need more configuration along with pointPlacement to center the column bars. I referred to this documentation -- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPlacement
2. For non-categorized x-axes, is there an alternative property to center the column bars on axis tickmarks?
3. I see that in my chart, pointPlacement values of “on” and “between” do not work as expected. Also a value of 0 does not center the column bar “on” the axis tickmarks (the documentation states it should)

Code

```
this.chart = new Chart({
      chart: {
        type: 'column',
      },
      title: {
        text: this.title
      },
      xAxis: {
        type: this.xType,
        startOnTick: true,
        min: moment(this.pointStart).add(1, 'days').unix() * 1000,
        tickInterval: this.xTickInterval,
        labels : {
          align: 'center'
        }
      },
      yAxis: {
        ...
      },
      tooltip : {
        ...
      },
      credits: {
        ...
      },
      plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPlacement: 0.4
          },
        series: {
          pointStart: this.pointStart ? moment(this.pointStart).unix() * 1000 : 0,
          pointInterval: this.pointInterval,
          showInLegend: false
        }
      },
      series: [{
        data: [],  //show empty grid initially
      }]
    });
```

Comment: please share code what you have tried so far

Comment: @NagaSaiA Added code.

Comment: Your code is not complete and it does not allow to reproduce the issue. Read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With basic config point placement seems to work correctly http://jsfiddle.net/57qx21s8/